# string declaration in action corresponding to a pattern affects next action corresponding to pattern

Tags: c, compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I extract the name of tag from input file on matching with pattern `"<"([a-z][a-z]*)`, subsequently extracting substring that contains only the name part in a string (character array) `tagName`, using the function `strncpy`.

Most seems to work well, when first `<div` is matched, except that the length of `tagName` which is the extracted substring obtained in `strncpy(tagName, yytext + 1, yytextlen - 1);` should be 3 for **div**, but get 6 instead.

During second match of input `<a`, the value of `tagName` during first match persists here and affects the output in action.

I am unable to understand the reason for this behaviour.

**Expected output:**

```
tagName: 0\y�� /* Garbage value */, tagName length: 6 /* Why is this 6 */
An html tag { yytext: <a, yyleng: 2, text: a, len: 1 }
```

**Current output**: Please see the **output** section below.

*I am using flex version 2.6.0 and gcc compiler on Ubuntu 16.*

---

**lex file:**

```
HTML_TAG    [a-z][a-z]*                                                                                              
REACT_TAG   [A-Z][[:alnum:]]*

%%

"<"{HTML_TAG}   {
  int yytextlen = yyleng;
  char tagName[yytextlen - 1];
  printf("tagName: %s, tagName length: %lu\n", tagName, strlen(tagName));
  strncpy(tagName, yytext + 1, yytextlen - 1);                                                                       
  printf("An html tag { yytext: %s, yyleng: %zu, text: %s, len: %lu }\n", yytext, yyleng, tagName, strlen(tagName)); 
  printf("\n\n");
} 

"<"{REACT_TAG}  {
                      printf("A react tag { text: %s, len: %zu }\n", yytext, yyleng);
                      printf("\n\n");
}                     

"</"{HTML_TAG}  {                                                                                                    
                      printf("A closing html tag { text: %s, len: %zu }\n", yytext, yyleng);                        
                      printf("\n\n");                                                                                
}                     

"</"{REACT_TAG} {                                                                                                    
                      printf("A closing react tag { text: %s, len: %zu }\n", yytext, yyleng);                       
                      printf("\n\n");                                                                                
}                     

[ \t\n] /* eat up whitespace */                                                                                      

.   ;

%%  

int main(int argc, char **argv)                                                                                      
{
  ++argv, --argc; /* skip over program name */                                                                       
  if (argc > 0)
    yyin = fopen(argv[0], "r");
  else
    yyin = stdin;

  yylex(); 
}
```

---

**Input file:**

```
<div
   attribute1=""
   attribute2=""
   attribute3=""
>
    <a>
        Text Content
    </a>
    <ReactTag attribute4="" />
    <ReactTag2 attribute5="">
        Text Content
    </ReactTag2>
</div>
```

---

**Output:**

```
tagName: 0\y��, tagName length: 6
An html tag { yytext: <div, yyleng: 4, text: div��, len: 6 }

tagName: div��, tagName length: 6
An html tag { yytext: <a, yyleng: 2, text: aiv��, len: 6 }

An closing html tag { text: </a, len: 3 }


A react tag { text: <ReactTag, len: 9 }


A react tag { text: <ReactTag2, len: 10 }


An closing react tag { text: </ReactTag2, len: 11 }


An closing html tag { text: </div, len: 5 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only looked at the action you indicated. If you make these same errors elsewhere, I'm sure you'll be able to find them.

Here's the `"<"{HTML_TAG}` action, with my commentaries:

```
{
  int yytextlen = yyleng;
```

What's the point of this variable? `yyleng` is not going to change its value during the execution of this action. Just use it.

```
  char tagName[yytextlen - 1];
```

You want to save a tagname whose with `yyleng - 1` characters (since `yyleng` includes the `<`.) That means you need a temporary string whose size is `yyleng - 1 + 1` (or `yyleng` for short), because you need to NUL-terminate the copy. Except you don't really need this copy. But we'll get back to that later.

```
  printf("tagName: %s, tagName length: %lu\n", tagName, strlen(tagName));
```

I know you're planning on copy `yytext` into `tagName`, but you haven't done it yet. So at this point it is uninitialised storage. Trying to print it is Undefined Behaviour. Trying to get its length with `strlen` is Undefined Behaviour. Obviously, this is going to print garbage. (Anyway, why do you need to *compute* `strlen`? You know exactly how long this string is going to be: `yyleng - 1`.)

```
  strncpy(tagName, yytext + 1, yytextlen - 1);
```

At some point I'm going to give up on this argument, but this is a great illustration of why you shouldn't use `strncpy` (except in the rare use case for which it was designed: fixed length database fields which don't require NUL termination). People seem to think `strncpy` is "safer" that `strcpy` because it has an `n` in its name. But it's actually extremely unsafe, even less safe than `strcpy`, because *it doesn't NUL-terminate the copy*. As we've seen above, you didn't leave enough space for the NUL terminator either, so if you had used `strcpy`, which does NUL terminate, then it would have written the NUL terminator outside of the buffer. But if you had made the buffer big enough, `strcpy` would have been exactly correct.

Also, in the case where the source string in a `strncpy` is shorter than the target, `strncpy` fills the rest of the target with NULs. All of it. This is almost always a waste of cycles (except in cases like this, where it writes no NULs at all and produces Undefined Behaviour).

If you really want to make a copy of a string limited to a maximum length, use `strndup` (if your C library includes it, which most do these days). `strndup` copies the string with a length limit. *And* it NUL-terminates the copy. *And* it dynamically allocates exactly enough space for the copy. If you want a safe interface, that's the one to use.

But why do you feel that you need to make a copy here? If you're planning to pass the token on to a parser, then you will indeed need a copy, but a local variable-length array is not the copy you will need, because the lifetime of the local array ends as soon as the action terminates, which is long before the copy could be used. If you did need a copy, you would need a dynamically-allocated copy. And that's precisely what `strndup` would have given you.

```
  printf("An html tag { yytext: %s, yyleng: %zu, text: %s, len: %lu }\n",
                        yytext, yyleng, tagName, strlen(tagName));
```

So now you have made your copy. But you made it with a library function that doesn't NUL-terminate, so it's still Undefined Behaviour to use the copy as though it were a string. It would only be a string if it were NUL-terminated. And it is still Undefined Behaviour to pass the copy to `strlen` as though it were a string.

On the other hand, printing out `yytext` and `yyleng` is just fine.

```
  printf("\n\n");
}
```

At this point, the action ends. `tagName` no longer exists. It's lifetime has come to an end. `yytext` is still OK, but not for long: as soon as the scanner starts looking for the next token (which is right away since your action doesn't `return` the token to its caller), it will take back control of `yytext`, modifying its contents in unpredictable ways. So if you had needed a copy of the string to return with the token type, you would have had to have already made a copy which was still alive.

Hope that all helps.

Comment: The answer to all the question in you commentaries is that, since I could not find an efficient way to debug the issue (expectation was to be able to use gdb like debugger), I was trying to understand the behaviour by introducing things like `yytextlen`,  `strlen`. Needless to say that led to further questions. You answer is most helpful, I will apply it now.

Comment: Also, I have been trying to understand the output of flex when used with option `‘-T, --trace, %option trace’`. But I could not find a documentation that specifies the format in which the output is printed. Please help me.

Comment: @haslo: you can use gdb with a flex-generated scanner. Compile with `-O0 -ggdb` and try to avoid the temptation to pack too much code on each line. The best is to just put the `{` on the line with the pattern, and start the action on the next line. You can set breakpoints by libe number in the `.l` file, since the generated file contains `#line` directives. Some versions of flex had an off-by-one bug in (some) line numbers; if you have this problem, upgrade.

Comment: @HasloVardos: as for the trace output, the most relevant line is the one which tells you it has accepted a token. It tells you the line number of the rule, followed by the contents of yytext --that is the text of the accepted token-- in parentheses. It also tells you about other events, including execution of the default rule.

Comment: If there are other lines which confuse you, feel free to ask a specific question about them (I mean, not in a comment.)